# What is the effect of calling a method of activity through its adapter connected with on Object Oriented Design of application?

Tags: java, android

What is the right way or best practice to call a method that is available in activity(this activity has a list view OR recycler view) from adapter that is connected with associative activity's list view. I have seen and used many times this way of coding to call method of activity from adapter

```
((MyActivity) context).abcMethod();
```

1)Is that the right way?
2)Is it not a violation of lose coupling?
3) Should I provide a callback interface for this tiny work?

What I read Classes should be losely coupled and interface is the key to accomplish this task.Kindly provide me better knowledge in this regards.

Comment: Use interface for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get instance of MyActivity in constructor in Adapter, and use to call method

//in Activity

```
MyAdapter my=new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this);
```

//In Adapter

```
    public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    MyActivity myActivity;
    public MyAdapter(MyActivity myActivity){
    this.myActivity=myActivity;
    }

//do your stuffs and call method by myActivity;
}
```

Thanks